# How to pass and call Snowflake stored procedure date argument in underlying SELECT statement as a column

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, javascript-objects

I am fairly new to snowflake working on a stored procedure having date as a parameter, the same parameter will be used in SELECT statement to work as additional column in result set.
Below is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1 (TEST_DATE VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE javascript
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
var prod = TEST_DATE;
var sql_stmt = `select
  ID
,Value
,getvariable('PROD') as TestDate
, to_varchar(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) CreateDate
from
Table;`;

var statement = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText:sql_stmt} );
        var rs = statement.execute();
        rs.next(1);
  //return rs.getColumnValue(1);
  return rs.getColumnValue(3);
   
 $$;
```

Calling above procedure as

```
CALL test1('2022-02-22');
```

Returning error as "NULL result in a non-nullable column".

Please suggest how can I use the argument as column name in select.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

[Binding Variables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript.html#binding-variables):

> Binding a variable to a SQL statement allows you to use the value of the variable in the statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1 (TEST_DATE VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE javascript
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$

var sql_stmt = `select
  ID
,Value
, :1 as TestDate
, to_varchar(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS CreateDate
from Table;`;

var statement = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText:sql_stmt, binds: [TEST_DATE]} );
var rs = statement.execute();
  ...
   
 $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Binding like mentioned above is the more proper method, but you could also use string formatting its a bit more readable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1 (TEST_DATE VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE javascript
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
var prod = TEST_DATE;
var sql_stmt = `select
  ID
,Value
,'${TEST_DATE}' as TestDate
, to_varchar(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) CreateDate
from
Table;`;

var statement = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText:sql_stmt} );
        var rs = statement.execute();
        rs.next(1);
  //return rs.getColumnValue(1);
  return rs.getColumnValue(3);
   
 $$;
```

Comment: I was receiving error with above code - ````Execution error in store procedure TEST: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 11 at position 2 unexpected '$'. At Statement.execute, line 19 position 27````

Comment: If you use this method, it's a direct string replacement. Unlike a bind variable, it needs to be wrapped with single quotes, so the code for that line would read `,'${TEST_DATE}' as TestDate`

Comment: Thanks @GregPavlik updated the response, missed that

Comment: After learning a bit more about Binding, I would now recommend not using my answer, and instead use Binding like the other recommendation.  If you happen to get a date that contains a ' it breaks your query while binding with handle it